# Setting selected value of dropdownlist causes other dropdownlists to also get that selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have several dropdownlists that I want to fill with drivers. The aspx is as follows:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DriversPolePositionDropDownList" runat="server" />
<br />
<asp:DropDownList ID="Drivers2ndPositionDropDownList" runat="server" />
<br />
<asp:DropDownList ID="Drivers3rdPositionDropDownList" runat="server" />
```

etc.

The problem is that after each dropdownlist has been filled with drivers, and I want to set the selected item of one dropdownlist it does so in ***all*** the dropdownlists. The dropdownlist getting filled with drivers is a separate step than selecting the value for the ddl's to display.

```
void AddDriver(string driverName, int driverId)
{
   ListItem item = new ListItem(driverName, driverId.ToString());
   AddItemToDropDownLists(item);
}
```

and then

```
string DriverPolePosition
{
   get { return DriversPolePositionDropDownList.SelectedValue; }
   set { DriversPolePositionDropDownList.SelectedValue = value; }
}
```

The code to set the selected value (it's only one dropdownlist I try to have the value of selected):

```
    predictionDetailsView.DriverPolePosition = 
response.SelectedDrivers[(int)DriverPositions.PolePosition];
```

How can I make it so that each dropdownlist can have its own selected value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right. So the problem was this piece of code:

```
AddItemToDropDownLists(item);
```

In the AddItemToDropDownLists method I gave *all* my dropdownlists the same list item. This makes them behave the same. The solution was to make a `new ListItem` for every dropdownlist.

Comment: I was making a single `List<ListItem>` and setting all my dropdownlists to use that list via `foreach...Items.AddRange(list.ToArray())`.  I moved creating the list to inside the `foreach` loop, limiting the scope of the list to setting that DDL.